# Have user's reach a consensus regarding a statement in a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, consensus

Is there a way for users interacting with the contract to reach a consensus regarding the truthiness of a statement?

For example: has the price gone up since 3 hours ago? True or False

Users will have financial incentives to lie. What is a good way to counter those incentives to lie about the truthiness of the statement? How can I have users successfully reach a consensus even though they have incentives to lie?

Answer (score 1):

you are describing  the [byzantine general problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance#The_Byzantine_Generals.27_Problem) which is hard to solve and this is why to reach consensus we need  proof of work. however for a simple Ethereum contract you could use an Oracle(third party) to check the truthiness of a statement.

Answer (score 1):

The basic options are:

- External data sources. I run Reality Keys for this purpose.
- Schelling games a la Augur where people bet on what everyone else will bet on, and you hope this will converge on the truth
- A forking token, where if there's a disagreement the token forks into parallel versions where different people won and you hope the one representing the truth is worth more
- A combination of the above